# How to stop Apple Mail from telling me to "Follow Up..."

Tags: mail.app, reminders

I really appreciate that MacOS' Apple Mail now is able to tell me that emails that I sent three days ago have not been responded to, and that I can "Follow Up..."

However, now, Apple Mail keeps reminding me of the same emails, over and over again, and archiving these threads has no effect on these reminder popping up again, minutes after I archive them.
The only action that seems to stop them from coming back is to delete the threads, but that's far from ideal.

How do I tell Apple Mail to stop reminding me to follow up on particular threads?

Comment: Right click > Ignore follow-up should work for a single mail/conversation.
I have no idea when this function was incorporated. One of my e-mails is tagged as "follow-up" even though I already responded to it, and the last e-mail in the conversation is mine.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that out. The threads that kept coming back for me decided to not keep coming back, for reasons unclear to me.

Comment: Well, a 'follow up' showed up again just now. Right-clicking anywhere doesn't do anything, but I do have an 'Ignore follow up' option under 'Message' in the main horizontal menu.

Comment: I added a full answer. Right click referred not to right clicking on the e-mail itself, but rather on the corresponding mail in the list of e-mails in the inbox.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can right click on the e-mail and select `Ignore follow-up` to ignore a single follow-up.

[image]

To fully turn off follow-ups, you can un-check the corresponding item in preferences.
[image: Preferences]

Comment: Oddly, I haven't had any follow up notices in the past two weeks to try this out.

Comment: I am getting follow-up suggestions even though I have "Enable message follow-up suggestions" turned off in the settings. They do go away after right-clicking or pulling down the Message menu and selecting Ignore follow-up. I have submitted a Feedback report to Apple.

Comment: i too have this turned off in both Mac & iPhone Mail settings, yet still i get these followup suggestions. opening the Mac Mail Settings, i can put a check in that option and watch the words "Follow Up" show up next to the suggested emails; then unchecking it, the words go away but the emails stay at the top even tho they're a week old! :-(